# Riemann integrable function that is zero at some point in every open interval

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f:[a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable. Suppose that for all $a < c < d < b$ exits a point $x \in ]c,d[$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Prove that $\int_a^bf = 0$.

I have tried to prove it using the Theorem of embedded intervals, so let two sequences {$c_n$} and {$d_n$} be such that both of them tend to $x$. Then at that point, $f(x)=0$ so we have $f(x)=0 \; \forall x \in [a,b]$. Then $\int_a^bf = 0$.

Comment: it may be false that $f(x)=0$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$. You are not asked to prove that, and it need not be true. But you may pick suitable points so that each Riemann sum is equal to $0$, and hence the integral is $0$. (It would have been true that $f(x)=0$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$, provided $f$ were continuous, but this is not given.) See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function an example that illustrates what might be given.

Comment: It is correct. And it is a consequence of the fact that the all upper sum are non-negative, while all the lower sums are non-positive. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is an immediate consequence of the definition of Riemann integral. Let $I=\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|S(P, f) - I|<\epsilon$ for all Riemann sums $$S(P, f) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$ with norm of $P$ less than $\delta$ and any choice of tags $t_{i} $ in interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$. Now we can choose the tags $t_{i}$ such that $f(t_{i}) =0$ so that $S(P, f) =0$ and then we have $|I|<\epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$ and hence $I=0$.

Answer (score 3):

For every partition $P=\{a=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=b\}$ let
$$
m_k=\inf_{t\in[t_{k-1},t_k]} \,f(t), \quad
M_k=\inf_{t\in[t_{k-1},t_k]} \,f(t)
$$
Clearly
$$
m_k\le 0 \le M_k,
$$
and hence for every partition $P$
$$
L(f,P)\le 0 \le U(f,P),
$$
and hence
$$
\sup_P L(f,P)\le 0 \le \inf_P U(f,P),
$$
Since $f$ is integrable, then $\sup_P L(f,P)= \inf_P U(f,P)=\int_a^b f$,
and hence $\int_a^b f=0$.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP knows the Lebesgue Criterion

Comment: @DavidBowman I have provided a more elementary proof.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\displaystyle \int_a^b f = \sup_{P}L(P,f)$, where $L$ denotes the lower sum, and the infimum is taken over all partitions. You know this because $f$ is Riemann integrable -- that's the definition (well, part of it). Now, using the fact that for any partition $P = \{t_0, t_1, \ldots t_n\}$, $L(P,f)=0$ (why?), what can you say?

Comment: $L(P,f)$is 0 because $\int_a^bf=0$, isnt it? But I dont know what can I say. I have though that if we take the partition $P = {t_0,t_1,t_2,..t_n}$ where $t_i = [c_i,d_i]$, and we calculate the sum of Riemann $\sum_{i=0}^nf(x)(d_i-c_i)$ that it is 0 because $f(x) = 0$

Comment: No, $L(P,f)$ is zero because the $inf$ of $f$ on any subinterval of your partition is $0$, by assumption. Then since $f$ is integrable, $\int f = L(P,f)$. Finally, you can't say $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$. You don't have that $f(x) =0$ everywhere (otherwise this would be trivial).

Comment: Why would $\inf$ of $f$ be $0$? The question says that there exists point in each subinterval where $f$ vanishes. It does not mean that $f$ can't be negative. Also your proof does not use the fact that $f$ is integrable. See the answer by Yiorgos S. Smyrlis where one finds that each lower sum is non-positive and each upper sum is non-negative.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I assumed $f$ was positive (incorrectly). However, my proof does use that $f$ is integrable -- I used the fact that the integral of $f$ is the sup of the lower sums.